# How to merge docx files without breaking tables between pages using python?

Tags: python

There are docx files that contain a table. Here is an example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58JhQ.png)

It is necessary that they all be combined into one file. But there is a problem, after the join, the tables are broken:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGKpa.png)

Here is the code I used:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.table import WD_ALIGN_VERTICAL
from docx.shared import Pt
import os

def merge_docx_files(input_folder, output_file):
    merged_document = Document()

    for file_name in os.listdir(input_folder):
        if file_name.endswith(".docx"):
            file_path = os.path.join(input_folder, file_name)
            doc = Document(file_path)

            for element in doc.element.body:
                merged_document.element.body.append(element)

            # Удаление разрывов между страницами для таблиц
            tables = merged_document.tables
            for table in tables:
                table.rows[-1].height_rule = None
                table.rows[-1].height = Pt(0)

                for row in table.rows:
                    for cell in row.cells:
                        cell.vertical_alignment = WD_ALIGN_VERTICAL.CENTER

    merged_document.save(output_file)
    print("Файлы успешно объединены в: {}".format(output_file))

# Пример использования
input_folder = r"C:\docx"
output_file = r"C:\docx\merged.docx"
merge_docx_files(input_folder, output_file)
```

I need this result:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1O4xAeP-ZY42dTLWBW__s7TE-Jek_maKc/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=110971285340817610332&rtpof=true&sd=true

Help me please! I did not find it on the Internet (((